# Ignoring zeros on log scale in Plots.jl

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Is it possible to plot data with a few zeros on a log-scale in Plots.jl? For example plot(0:10, yscale=:log10) gives an error, but I would like it to just ignore the one zero value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not, and likely will not ever be.

An easy workaround is to replace `plot(y)` with `plot(y[y.>0])`, or `plot(x,y)` with

```
inds = (x .> 0) .& (y .> 0)
plot(x[inds],y[inds])
```

Comment: But you can filter them yourself.

Comment: Right, added that to the answer.